# Magento2 print customer full data array

Tags: magento2, customer

How to print customer array full data.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customermodel,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $addressmodel,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customer
)
{
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_address = $addressmodel;
    $this->_customermodel = $customermodel;
}
$customerData = $this->_customer->getById($customerId);
```

How to print this `$customerData` ?

Comment: check like that print_r($customerData->getData());

Comment: Did you try with $customerData->getData()?

Comment: Hi Emipro ,  now i am getting follwing error:
"code": 500,
    "message": "Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::getData()'

Comment: $customerData = $this->_customer->getById($customerId);
foreach($customerData as $customer){
 print_r($customer->getData());
} try with this

Comment: Hi Rakesh, it displaying Blank.
if we print $customerData ->getEmail()..we are getting emailid.

Comment: getting "code": 500,
    "message": "Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::debug()' in

Comment: $customerData = $this->_customer->getById($customerId); foreach($customerData as $customer){ print_r($customer->debug());

Comment: foreach($customerData as $customer){
       print_r($customer->debug()) ;
      }
not working..."code": 500,
    "message": "Fatal Error: 'Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Customer::debug()'

Comment: Yes have you try with this

Comment: Yes i have tried...getting error code 500

Answer (score 7):

In Magento 1, any class which extended from `Varien_Object` had access to a method `getData` which would return the data property of the class as an array.

In Magento 2, there is no `Varien_Object` and no `getData` method. Data Models still have a data property, however, but it is of protected visibility and there is no accessor method for the whole array.

The only way to get at this property, then, is to use the `__toArray` method, in order to tell Magento to create an array representation of the data property.

This method is defined in `\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`, so you will only be able to use it if this class is in your model's inheritance tree.

```
<?php

// Inject your customer dependency in the usual way

/** @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface */
$customerData = $customer->__toArray();

var_dump($customerData);

// Outputs something like:

array(22) {
  'website_id' =>
  string(1) "1"
  'email' =>
  string(34) "me@example.com"
  'group_id' =>
  string(2) "17"
  'store_id' =>
  string(1) "1"
  'created_at' =>
  string(19) "2018-04-06 15:52:34"
  'updated_at' =>
  string(19) "2018-06-26 13:42:09"
  'disable_auto_group_change' =>
  string(1) "0"
  'created_in' =>
  string(18) "Default Store View"

  ...Output truncated
```

A word of warning before copy-pasting the above, however: The code snippet above depends on whether your Customer Data Model also extends from `\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`.

The default, as defined in `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/di.xml` specifies `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` as the concrete implementation, which does include `\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject` in it's inheritance tree, which is why the code snippet above works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and thumps up.

**Using Dependency Injection:**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer        
)
{
    $this->_customer = $customer;       
}

public function execute(){
  //Loading customer information using customer id
  customerId = 10;
  $customer = $this->_customer->create()->load(customerId);

  //To get customer account information
  echo '<pre>';print_r($customer->getData());

  //To get customer address information
  $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
  if(count($addresses) > 0){
    foreach($addresses as $address){
      print_r($address->getOrigData());
    }
  }
}
```

**Using Object manager:**

```
$customerId = 10;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$customerModel = $customer->create()->load($customerId);

//To get customer account information
  echo '<pre>';print_r($customerModel->getData());

  //To get customer address information
  $addresses = $customerModel->getAddresses();
  if(count($addresses) > 0){
    foreach($addresses as $address){
      print_r($address->getOrigData());
    }
  }
```